# Accessing other than first element in list doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

In my DataFrame I have list with dicts. When I do

```
data.stations.apply(lambda x: x)[5]
```

the output is:

```
[{'id': 245855,
'outlets': [{'connector': 13, 'id': 514162, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 3, 'id': 514161, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 7, 'id': 514160, 'power': 0}]},
 {'id': 245856,
  'outlets': [{'connector': 13, 'id': 514165, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 3, 'id': 514164, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 7, 'id': 514163, 'power': 0}]},
 {'id': 245857,
  'outlets': [{'connector': 13, 'id': 514168, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 3, 'id': 514167, 'power': 0},
   {'connector': 7, 'id': 514166, 'power': 0}]}]
```

So it looks like 3 dicts in a list.

When I do

```
data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[0] )[5]
```

It does what it should:

```
{'id': 245855,
 'outlets': [{'connector': 13, 'id': 514162, 'power': 0},
  {'connector': 3, 'id': 514161, 'power': 0},
  {'connector': 7, 'id': 514160, 'power': 0}]}
```

HOWEVER, when I chose second or third element, it doesn't work:

```
data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[1])[5]
```

This gives an  error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-1210ba659690> in <module>()
----> 1 data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[1])[5]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\geo2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2549             else:
   2550                 values = self.asobject
-> 2551                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2552 
   2553         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-118-1210ba659690> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[1])[5]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why? It should just give me the second element.

Comment: what is the index [5] refering to?

Comment: Fifth element from the DataFrame

Comment: @MikalojM can you add the output of `data.stations.head()`?

Comment: @Dark

Here it is:

0      [{'outlets': [{'connector': 7, 'id': 340304, '...
1      [{'network_id': 8, 'outlets': [{'connector': 6...
10     [{'outlets': [{'connector': 10, 'id': 364859, ...
100    [{'outlets': [{'connector': 10, 'id': 329118, ...
101    [{'outlets': [{'connector': 14, 'id': 462278, ...
Name: stations, dtype: object

Comment: I'll paste it in the question

Comment: @MikalojM, there are chances that the stations column might not have exactly 3 dicts in every row. So this might give you the second dict 
 `data.loc[5].stations[1]`. Check the dataframe once and make sure all the rows have the 3 dict entries.

Comment: I know, but I'm still accessing the same element in the DataFrame with those two - the fifth element:
data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[0] )[5]

data.stations.apply(lambda x: x[1])[5]

Comment: and data.loc[5].stations.apply(lambda x: x[1] ) gives error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-9913db712dfc> in <module>()
----> 1 data.loc[5].stations.apply(lambda x: x[1] )

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: You are first accessing 2nd element of the list in every row using apply then selecting the 5 the row.

Comment: oh you're right, thank you good sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason might be simple that all the list entries in each row might not be of same length. Lets consider an example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'stations':[[{'1':2,'3':4},{'1':2,'3':4},{'1':2,'3':4}],
                                [{'1':2,'3':4},{'1':2,'3':4}],
                                [{'1':2,'3':4}],
                                 [{'1':2,'3':4},{'1':2,'3':4},{'1':2,'3':4}]]
                    })

                                         stations
0  [{'1': 2, '3': 4}, {'1': 2, '3': 4}, {'1': 2, ...
1               [{'1': 2, '3': 4}, {'1': 2, '3': 4}]
2                                 [{'1': 2, '3': 4}]
3  [{'1': 2, '3': 4}, {'1': 2, '3': 4}, {'1': 2, ...
```

If you do :

```
data['stations'].apply(lambda x: x[0])[3]
```

You will get :

```
{'1': 2, '3': 4}
```

But if you do:

```
data['stations'].apply(lambda x: x[1])[3]
```

You will get `Index Error... list out of bounds` because if you observe the 3rd row there is only one element in the list. Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: hi @Dark, pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196539/finding-shortest-values-between-the-cities-in-a-dataframe