# Finding shortest values between the cities in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, networkx, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a dataframe with cities and distance between other cities from each city. My dataset looks like,

df,

```
 From City      City A  City B City C  City D
 City A                 2166    577     175
 City B         2166            1806    2092
 City C         577     1806            653
 City D         175     2092    653
```

im planning to visit all the cities, I am trying to find in which order by cities I can travel with the shortest distance. I want to end with a starting position. **start point and end point should be same.**

Is there a way to find this shortest distance across all the cities, or any other approach is available. please help.

Comment: I strongly recommend looking into this: https://github.com/dmishin/tsp-solver

Comment: Your problem is effectively solving the TSP.

Comment: any documentation?

Comment: Literally any solver that uses adjacency matrices as input should work. I'm not sure cdist is a good answer @Dark because travelling salesman is an NP Hard problem.

Comment: yes, @Dark solution finds the nearest value in the same column, I want to route through all the columns and finds the shortest order of column where we can visit all the cities with lesser distance.

Comment: @pyd yeah `tsp-solver` is what you might be after.

Comment: You might need to install tsp-solver then use `pd.Series(tsp_solver.greedy.solve_tsp(df.fillna(0).values)).replace(dict(enumerate(df.columns)))`. Hope it helps

Comment: @pyd first thing's first replace all the missing values with nan or zero. Then use the above code. When you are dealing with numbers there shldn't be any object dtypes in the dataframe.

Comment: ya got it, should I remove my first column "From City" and try?

Comment: how can I give starting and end points

Comment: found it, works great. Thanks @Dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer. I've been facing the same problem. Leaving a solution (in case someone needs it) with [`tsp_solver`](https://github.com/dmishin/tsp-solver) to solve the TSP and [`networkx`](https://networkx.org), [`pygraphviz`](https://pygraphviz.github.io) to plot the results graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tsp_solver.greedy import solve_tsp
from tsp_solver.util import path_cost

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import networkx as nx

# for Jupyter Notebook
from IPython.display import Image
```

Define the distances matrix DataFrame

```
# Define distances matrix dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [np.nan, 2166, 577, 175],
    'B': [2166, np.nan, 1806, 2092],
    'C': [577, 1806, np.nan, 653],
    'D': [175, 2092, 653, np.nan]
}, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df)

        A       B       C       D
A     NaN  2166.0   577.0   175.0
B  2166.0     NaN  1806.0  2092.0
C   577.0  1806.0     NaN   653.0
D   175.0  2092.0   653.0     NaN
```

Fill `NaN`s

```
# Fill NaNs with 0s
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# plot the matrix
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='.0f', cmap="YlGnBu")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Take the lower nilpotent triangular matrix (square symmetric distance matrix)

```
# Take the lower nilpotent triangular matrix
lower_nilpotent_triangular_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.tril(df),
    columns=df.columns,
    index=df.index
)
print(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df)

        A       B      C    D
A     0.0     0.0    0.0  0.0
B  2166.0     0.0    0.0  0.0
C   577.0  1806.0    0.0  0.0
D   175.0  2092.0  653.0  0.0
```

```
# mask
mask = np.zeros_like(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
# plot the matrix
sns.heatmap(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df, 
            annot=True, fmt='.0f', 
            cmap="YlGnBu", mask=mask)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Solve the circular Traveling Salesman Problem

```
# Solve the circular shortest path
# NOTE: since it is circular, endpoints=(0,0)
#       is equal to endpoints=(1,1) etc...
path = solve_tsp(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.to_numpy(), endpoints=(0, 0))
path_len = path_cost(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.to_numpy(), path)
# Take path labels from df
path_labels = df.columns[path].to_numpy()
print('shortest circular path:', path_labels)
print('path length:', path_len)

shortest circular path: ['A' 'D' 'B' 'C' 'A']
path length: 4650.0
```

Plot the graph with the shortest path

```
# Define graph edges widths
shortest_path_widths = df.copy(deep=True)
shortest_path_widths.loc[:,:] = .25
for idx0, idx1 in zip(path_labels[:-1], path_labels[1:]):
    shortest_path_widths.loc[idx0, idx1] = 4.
    shortest_path_widths.loc[idx1, idx0] = 4.
```

```
# Show the graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
for r in lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.columns:
    for c in lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.index:
        if not lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.loc[r, c]:
            continue
        G.add_edge(
            r, c,
            # scaled edge length
            length=lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.loc[r, c]/250,
            # edge label
            label=int(lower_nilpotent_triangular_df.loc[r, c]),
            # no direction
            dir='none', 
            # edge width
            penwidth=shortest_path_widths.loc[r, c]
        )

# Add attributes
for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
    d['label'] = d.get('label','')
    d['len'] = d.get('length','')
    d['penwidth'] = d.get('penwidth','')

A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
A.node_attr.update(color="skyblue", style="filled", 
                   shape='circle', height=.4, 
                   fixedsize=True)
A.edge_attr.update(color="black", fontsize=10)

A.draw('cities.png', format='png', prog='neato')
# Show image in Jupyter Notebook
Image('cities.png')
```

[image]