# how to find shortest path between all the cities with starting and end points

Tags: pandas, networkx, shortest-path

I have a dataframe like this,

```
 From City      City A  City B City C  City D
 City A                 2166    577     175
 City B         2166            1806    2092
 City C         577     1806            653
 City D         175     2092    653
```

I found the shortest path order using `tsp-solver` but I want to find the shortest path order with **starting and ending points**. pls help

expected output:

if i select, city B is my starting point,
it should return a list of cities starting from City B and route through all the cities with the shortest path

Comment: Can you add more deteails? how should the output be?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: for A should it be: ‘[City D, City C, City B]‘?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understood the question correctly, but if you want an ordered list of the cities with the shortest path form the selected city, you can do it so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"From city": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'A':[np.NaN,2166,577,175], 'B':[2166,np.NaN,1806,2092], 'C':[577,1806,np.NaN,653], 'D':[175,2092,653,np.NaN]})
df.set_index('From city', inplace=True)
print df
                A       B       C       D
From city                                
A             NaN  2166.0   577.0   175.0
B          2166.0     NaN  1806.0  2092.0
C           577.0  1806.0     NaN   653.0
D           175.0  2092.0   653.0     NaN

dic = df.to_dict(orient='records')
city=dic[3]
from math import isnan
city = {k: city[k] for k in city if not isnan(city[k])}
city_order = sorted(city.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
city_list = [i[0] for i in city_order]
```

Explanation:

Make a dictionary from the df:

```
dic = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Select you city(for city 'D'->3)

```
city=dic[3]
```

Remove the NaN element

```
from math import isnan
city = {k: city[k] for k in city if not isnan(city[k])}
```

Order

```
city_order = sorted(city.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Take only the cities:

```
city_list = [i[0] for i in city_order]
print city_list
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C', 'B']
```

Comment: Joe, thanks for your solution, actually I posted a question and I could not achieve the starting and ending postion that's why I posted this solution. Please check my first question for better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196539/finding-shortest-values-between-the-cities-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment87410500_50196539

Comment: Did you see my previous question